# Change workspaces layout in Unity 2D

Tags: 11.10, unity-2d, workspaces

I was using a workspace layout or 1 row and 5 columns, but with the latest update of Unity 2d , now my 5 workspaces are splited in 2 rows.

How should I revert the layout workspace back to 1 row?

Many thanks!

Comment: I don't think this is possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Install the old GNOME panel by running the following command in a terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-panel
```

Then start it up:

```
gnome-panel
```

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+Right-Click the "desktops" panel applet (at the bottom right) and choose *Preferences*.

Set the number of rows to what you want. You can now uninstall the gnome-panel if you like.

Comment: But this solution loses the layout after shutting down and starting the session again. It happened to me using on 12.04. I haven't uninstalled gnome-panel.