# How to change V Desktop and H Desktop in Ubuntu 2D?

Tags: 12.04, compiz, unity-2d, metacity, myunity

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Change workspaces layout in Unity 2D](https://askubuntu.com/questions/88624/change-workspaces-layout-in-unity-2d)

I want to change the desktops/workplaces from **2x2** to **5x1** but it is not possible using **CCSM** (CompizConfig) nor **MyUnity**.

I've tried to use **gconf-editor**, by changing the value of the key **apps** > **metacity** > **num_workspaces** to **5**, but it gets **3x2** without the last (sixth) desktop/workplace.

Does any one know how to do it on Unity 2D? On Ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: It's duplicated. I hadn't found it before. The original [Change workspaces layout in Unity 2D](http://askubuntu.com/questions/88624/change-workspaces-layout-in-unity-2d) has a solution that works.

Comment: But the solution above loses the layout after shutting down and starting the session again.